# Substring and UpsertDE

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am trying to update my Data Extension;s FirstName and LastName columns based on the values resulting from substring. If I test the email without UpsertDE it works, if I add the UpserdDE function it doesn't work - no update on the data extension and also the email is not sent.

```
%%[

var @Name, @first_name, @last_name, @FirstName, @LastName

set @Name = AttributeValue('Name')
set @first_name = substring(@Name,1,subtract(indexOf(@Name,' '),1))
set @Last_name = substring(@Name,1,subtract(indexOf(@Name,' '),2))

set @FirstName = v(@first_name)
set @LastName = v(@last_name)

UpsertDE('AMPscript Functions 1', 1, 'FirstName', v(@first_name), 'LastName', v(@last_name))

]%%
```

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**

Based on your answer (which has been deleted as it was posed as a question/comment and not an answer) I believe the issue you had in your new code was that you did not define the `@Email` variable.  See updated code below.  If this does not answer your issue still, please let me know what error you are getting when you preview the email with that code in it.

---

I believe your issue is that you are not including a primary key for it to match on in your upsertDE function.  That combined with that you do not need to use the `v()` function inside of AMPscript blocks is likely what is causing issues. Also, your substring for last name is not correct. I added in the correct beginning and ending of your substring for that as well.

See below for example code: (replace `"PrimaryKey"` and `@PrimaryKey` with your primary key name and values.)

```
%%[

var @Name, @first_name, @last_name, @FirstName, @LastName

set @Email = AttributeValue('emailaddr')
set @Name = AttributeValue('Name')
set @first_name = substring(@Name,1,subtract(indexOf(@Name,' '),1))
set @Last_name = substring(@Name,ADD(indexOf(@Name,' '), 1),Length(@Name))

set @FirstName = @first_name
set @LastName = @last_name

UpsertDE('AMPscript Functions 1', 1, "Email", @Email, 'FirstName', @first_name, 'LastName', @last_name)

]%%
```

I am not sure why you are duplicating FirstName and LastName vars, when you can just name the initial vars differently. See below for sample of what I mean:

```
%%[

var @Name, @first_name, @last_name, @FirstName, @LastName

set @Email = AttributeValue('emailaddr')
set @Name = AttributeValue('Name')
set @FirstName = substring(@Name,1,subtract(indexOf(@Name,' '),1))
set @LastName = substring(@Name,ADD(indexOf(@Name,' '), 1),Length(@Name))

UpsertDE('AMPscript Functions 1', 1, "Email", @Email, 'FirstName', @FirstName, 'LastName', @LastName)

]%%
```